# Error using DropNet

Tags: c#, dropbox, dropnet

I have the following error when using DropNet library to make connection to DropBox.

Trying to implement it for my CMS and also for my knowledge :)

trying the current documentation of DropNet.
Source:https://github.com/DropNet/DropNet

**Current code:**

```
var  _client = new DropNetClient(Core.DropBoxAPI, Core.DropBoxKeySecret);
UserLogin login = _client.GetToken();
_client.UserLogin = login;
String Url = _client.BuildAuthorizeUrl();
```

**Produces:**

> Received Response [Unauthorized] : Expected to see [OK]. The HTTP
>   response was [{"error": "Unauthorized"}].
>
> Exception: DropNet.Exceptions.DropboxRestException: Received Response
>   [Unauthorized] : Expected to see [OK]. The HTTP response was
>   [{"error": "Unauthorized"}].

I want to let the user connect to the Url returned by `_client.BuildAuthorizeUrl();` but it even won't let me get to url
and i also have a Key and Secret generated from DropBox.com
if i try to set the method `_client.BuildAuthorizeUrl();` as first statement it gives also an error on the DropBox page itselfs.

I tried to find an another post on Stackoverflow but i didn't find any solution so fare.

Its still using the basics of the documentation and it goes wrong.
If you have any ideas that would be nice.

Thanks for the advices.

Answer (score 0):

I was filling the secret the same as the APP key.